# Where to get a x.509 Certificate to Encrypt a SOAP message

Tags: web-services, encryption, soap, x509certificate, soap-client

I'm calling a web service hosted by a 3rd party and they require that I encrypt the actual SOAP message with a x.509 certificate (they are using asymmetric encryption)

The certificate I use needs to be signed by a root Certificate Authority.  In searching online, I am finding mostly references to SSL certificates, but from what I've read, this is different from what I need.  If that is correct, can someone provide a link to a page on a Certificate Authority's website where I would be able to purchase the certificate I need.  I haven't had any luck and it's driving me crazy.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.  Let me know if you need further details.
-Chris

Comment: The SSL cert should do what you need.  It is a public/private key pair.  If I were you, I'd ask the third party about testing it using a self-signed certificate or a certificate they sign with their own testing CA. (I am assuming you are calling a hosted web service.)

Comment: Yes, it's a hosted web service.  Thanks for your help.